# CoreData: error: Serious application error

Tags: core-data, ios7, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am saving the data in local DB which is coming from server. 
And i use NSFetchedResultsController to show data. But i get an error "**CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to insert row 12 into section 1, but there are only 12 rows in section 1 after the update with userInfo (null)".**
And list get currupted. As shown in screen shot.

[image]
Please suggest the reason for this

Comment: probably your code has some errors.

Comment: You might want to describe how you added the 12 items and show what your code does...